# как получать через функцию значение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как получать через функцию значение?

с `15.12.2021`

получать `2021-12-15`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function convert(input) {
  return input.split('.').reverse().join('-');
}
const start = '15.12.2021';
const end = convert(start);
console.log(start, end);
```